# Maintain different variants of an app using GIT

Tags: git

I am currently developing an application for a couple of clients. The codebase is 99% common in both of them, as it is an invoicing app and the principles are the same. However, there are some minor special needs for each "edition" which are not easy to control via settings (different fields in forms, etc).

I'd like to manage the main codebase with GIT, as well as the "edition-specific" files, which will be 4-5 files tops. I've been reading suggestions and I've seen that a good approach would be to have a master branch with all the codebase and a specific branch for each edition, merging common changes from master to each specific branch and commiting specific changes in each branch.

Is this a good approach? I'm not sure how to get there from what I have now: if I branch now and then delete the edition-specific files from the master branch, won't it merge the delete to the specific branches?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You *could* use one branch for common code, and merge that into each project branch, but that feels like a very odd way to approximate a git `submodule` or `subtree`. If you've got a good subdirectory structure you can work with, I highly recommend using git `subtree`.

> Submodules
>
> It often happens that while working on one project, you need to use another project from within it. Perhaps it’s a library that a third party developed or that you’re developing separately and using in multiple parent projects. A common issue arises in these scenarios: you want to be able to treat the two projects as separate yet still be able to use one from within the other.

source: http://www.git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-Tools-Submodules

> Subtree Merging
>
> [...] The idea of the subtree merge is that you have two projects, and one of the projects maps to a subdirectory of the other one and vice versa. When you specify a subtree merge, Git is smart enough to figure out that one is a subtree of the other and merge appropriately — it’s pretty amazing.

source: http://www.git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-Tools-Subtree-Merging

Comment: +1. Branches are meant for feature development, using them for configuration management can get very complex very fast. Advice I once got, did not want to follow, than eventually had to: "do not create a branch that you don't want to eventually merge or discard".

Comment: Key phrase here is "If you've got a good subdirectory structure you can work with". `subtree` won't work if the common code between projects cannot be neatly compartmentalized.

Answer (score 1):

I see this working well on a relatively small scale, limited number of deployments, a small, disciplined team, and not too much commits between refreshes and on the customized branches.

However I also see this having a hockeystick shaped complexity curve and when growing you might hit a wall at speed. If you see this scaling up, you'll have to look at some form of modularisation/plugins architecturu in time to avoid running into that.

When you see that integrating changes start hurting (often breakage occurs when pulling the latest master) then that should be your red flag.